# Сортировка двумерного списка

Tags: python

Извините за глупый вопрос, но я не очень хорош в сортировке.
У меня есть двумерный массив, например:

```
[[John,3],[Nick,8],[Jane,5],[Bob,15]]
```

Как я могу получить на выходе массив, в таком же виде, но отсортированные по числу от большего к меньшему массивы? Тоесть на выходе я хочу получить следующее:

```
[[Bob,15],[Nick,8],[Jane,5],[John,3]]
```

Comment: К слову говоря, если Вы под именами имели в виду строки, то либо надо было их прописать над списком, либо закавычить их (`'John', 'Nick', 'Jane', 'Bob'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого используем стандартную функцию сортировку списков [`sort(reverse, key)`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_sort.asp), но при этом в аргументы вставляем следующие значения:

- `reverse=True` — возвращает список в обратном порядке (т.е. с большего к меньшему);
- `key=lambda x: x[1]` — тут мы используем [анонимную функцию (или лямбда-функцию)](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/vse-chto-nuzhno-znat-o-lambda-funkcijah-v-python), которая передаёт функции сортировки значение, по которому нужно проводить проверку. `lambda x` означает `x` как элемент исходного списка, после двоеточия берётся элемент, по которому и будет происходить сортировка: `x[1]`.

```py
lst = [['John',3],['Nick',8],['Jane',5],['Bob',15]]

lst.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
```